Merge and edit documents function in Word is asking permission for all records
I have successfully set up a conditional merge in Word linked to a csv file.  It has always worked easily in the past by asking one time to approve the data source.  All of the sudden when I go to merge and edit the documents a dialogue box appears asking for permission to access the data source for each of the 400 records.  How do I make this go away.  I use this function often and cannot spend the time to approve each individual merge.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

What popups are you seeing? At the beginning, you normally see the one that displays the SQL command and asks to continue. Are you seeing that dialog box for every record, or a different one (for example, you might be seeing one that asks about the delimiter characters for each record). Also, is there a { DATABASE } field in your mail merge main document?
